# file compressed through command "pv" are different from ordinary compressed file

Tags: sh, pv, compressed-files

here is my script:

`tar cf - testdir | pv -s $(du -sb testdir | awk '{print $1}') | pigz -1 > pv.tar.gz`

`tar cf - testdir | pigz -1 > nopv.tar.gz`

`diff pv.tar.gz nopv.tar.gz`

and then the output is "Binary files pv.tar.gz and nopv.tar.gz differ".

I execute `hexdump`

and I found that only the first line of these two files is slightly different

pv.tar.gz: 8b1f 0008 **9e24** 5fc8 0304 bdec 5f7b c71b

nopv.tar.gz: 8b1f 0008 **9c18** 5fc8 0304 bdec 5f7b c71b

But after I unzipped it and compared it again, the testdir is exactly the same.

What I want to ask is, how can I make the two tar.gz files consistent?

Comment: Your hexdump looks wrong. The first 4 bytes should be `8b 1f 08 00`, not `...00 08`. Can you confirm that you typoed them, or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not to do with `pv`. Bytes 5 to 8 in a gzip header are the timestamp. This will be different each time you run the command. You can tell `pigz` not to store it with the `-m` switch, so your commands are:

```
tar cf - testdir | pv -s $(du -sb testdir | awk '{print $1}') | pigz -1 -m > pv.tar.gz

tar cf - testdir | pigz -1 -m > nopv.tar.gz
```

which should give you the same content. You'll notice when you `hexdump` that the values that changed are all `00` now.